# React Native Drawer doesn't close automatically

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, drawer

I implemented a simple drawer according to a react native guide. I can see the drawer and toggle between the two linked frames. However the drawer itself doesn't collapse. So the actual frame is hidden behind the drawer.

The whole guide (the the code) that I used can be found here: https://github.com/iamshaunjp/react-native-tutorial/tree/lesson-24/gamezone

This issue exists also when cloning this branch.

```
import { createDrawerNavigator } from 'react-navigation-drawer';
import { createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';

// stacks
import HomeStack from './homeStack';
import AboutStack from './aboutStack';

const routeConfig = { 
   Home: {
  screen: HomeStack,
},
About: {
  screen: AboutStack,
}

}

// drawer navigation options
const RootDrawerNavigator = createDrawerNavigator(routeConfig);

export default createAppContainer(RootDrawerNavigator);
```

```
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack';
import About from '../screens/about';

const screens = {
  About: {
    screen: About,
    navigationOptions: {
      title: 'About GameZone'
    },
  },
}

const AboutStack = createStackNavigator(screens, {
  defaultNavigationOptions: {
    headerTintColor: '#444',
    headerStyle: { backgroundColor: '#eee', height: 60 },
  }
});

export default AboutStack;
```